# Server requring default text field values by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Depending on a users selection, a text field box remains hidden:

```
$("#aForm").on("change", function() { 
if ($(this).val() == "a") 
    $("#textField").hide();
else 
    $("#textField").show(); 
});
```

Problem is server is expecting a value in the `textfield` box. So how would I be able to insert just an empty string which is then sent to the server even though the text box is hidden?

Comment: question essentially outlines that you have no form validation which doesn't sound good. There are tons of resources on web regarding validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden values still send values to the server. So you can just set the default value when you toggle the show/hide.

```
$("#aForm").on("change", function() { 
    if ($(this).val() == "a") {
        $("#textField").hide();
        $("#textField").val("This textbox is hidden and has a default value");
    } else {
        $("#textField").show(); 
        $("#textField").val(""); // reset the value
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks...but including those 2  extra lines, prevents the textfield from being hidden now.

Comment: Are you getting an error? And is #textField an input field or is it a wrapper for the input?

Comment: No error. This is the textField: `<input type="text" style="width:285px" name="textField" id="textField"/>`

Comment: What type of element is `aForm`?

Comment: `aForm` is a `select` element

Comment: Thanks...Did a sanity check and I was mixing up my `name` and `id` values.